# Git-Tower Not Tracking

Tags: git, github, git-tower

I am attempted to make commits for a school project to my Github repository though the use of the Git-Tower application. For some reason it is saying No Tracking for the branch. How can I fix that so that when I click on a file I can see what the file looks like.

[image]

Comment: This is actually several questions, not one. "Not tracking" is about connecting to a GitHub repository. See GitHub help for is. Seeing the file contents is (or isn't) a feature of Git-Tower.

Comment: I came to find out that the reason I was receiving this was because somehow in the parent directory was also a "repository". So that was the reason why it wouldn't give me commits.